# iOS/Objective-C: App crashing after deleting rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When I try to delete an object/row from this UItable, the apllication crashes with the log:

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid
>   number of rows in section 0.

EDIT:

There are changes in the code, now new objects are inserted, and the deleted object is actually deleted, but only after the crash and restart... so, the deletion still fails with the same log, invalid uptade...The new code:

```
    @interface TableViewController ()

@property NSMutableArray *users;
@property NSArray *detailList;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *locations;


@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (IBAction)delete:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    self.tableView.editing = !self.tableView.editing;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    self.detailList=@[@"Your Favourite Spots",@"Our suggestion"];

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    _locations = [[Spot spotType:@"users"]mutableCopy];
    _users=[[Spot spotWithType:@"users"]mutableCopy];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}


#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    return 2;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.detailList objectAtIndex:section];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *places=[self containerWithSection:section];

    return places.count; 
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSArray *places=[self containerWithSection:indexPath.section];
    Spot *spot = [places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", spot.name]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"detail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        NSArray *places = [self containerWithSection:indexPath.section];

        DetailViewController * destination = segue.destinationViewController;

        destination.spot =  [places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    }
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSPersistentContainer *persistenceContainer = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].persistentContainer;

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = persistenceContainer.viewContext;

        NSMutableArray *places = [self containerWithSection:indexPath.section];

        Spot *spot = [places objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [context deleteObject: spot];

        NSError *error;

        [context save:&error];

        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

        [places removeObject:spot];


        [self updateItemInSection:indexPath.section];


        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [tableView reloadData];

}

#pragma mark - Aux methods

- (void)updateItemInSection:(NSUInteger)section{

    switch (section) {
        case 0:{
            _locations = [[Spot allSpots]mutableCopy];
        }
            break;

        case 1:{
            _users = [[Spot spotType:@"users"]mutableCopy];
        }
            break;    
    }
}


#pragma mark - Aux methods

- (NSMutableArray*)containerWithSection:(NSUInteger)section {

    NSMutableArray *thisContainer;

    switch (section) {

        case 0:
            thisContainer = self.locations;
            break;

        case 1:
            thisContainer = self.users;
            break;   
    }
    return thisContainer;  
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After delete/insert a data object, you need to first update your data array before asking the table to reloadData. This is the reason for the crash as well as table not getting updated with new elements.
 *Would we a good learning curve if you factor in this reasoning & try once to make the necessary changes in your code.*
Just remember, on any change, inserting, deletion of data => first, update your data arrays => then, `[table reloadData]` 
So, now for handling deletion of cells, we'll be adding a *new* function `updateItemInSection:` responsible for performing table data update & will be invoked from `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`

Here's how its gonna look like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSPersistentContainer *persistenceContainer = [AppDelegate sharedDelegate].persistentContainer;

        NSManagedObjectContext *context = persistenceContainer.viewContext;

        NSManagedObject *spot = [_lisbonSpots objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        [context deleteObject: spot];

        NSError *error;

        [context save:&error];

        if (!error) {
           NSLog(@"%@", error);        
        }

        [_lisbonSpots removeObject:spot];

        // new function invocation here
        [self updateItemInSection:indexPath.section]; 

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}

- (void)updateItemInSection:(NSUInteger)section{

    switch (section) {
        case 0:{
            _bar = [Spot spotType:@"bar"];
        }
            break;

        case 1:{
            _restaurant = [Spot spotType:@"restaurant"];
        }
            break;

        case 2:{
            _club = [Spot spotType:@"club"];
        }
            break;

        case 3:{
            _others = [Spot spotType:@"others"];
        }
            break;
    }
}

- (NSArray*)containerWithSection:(NSUInteger)section {

    NSArray *thisContainer;

    switch (section) {

        case 0:
            thisContainer = self.bar;
            break;

        case 1:
            thisContainer = self.restaurant;
            break;

        case 2:
            thisContainer = self.club;
            break;

        case 3:
            thisContainer = self.others;
            break;
    }

    return thisContainer;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, but how can I update this mutable array? Is is ti just bellow this line? [_lisbonSpots removeObject:spot];

Comment: @FuManchu Check the edits. Try to grasp the role of `updateItemInSection:` function here. This is a very common table design pattern you'll encounter in future as well. :)

Comment: You're saying that a new method - updateItemInSection - is needed so later can be called in the edit. This method will update, like it says, the item in section; but coredata doesnt do that automatically?

Comment: @FuManchu Core Data handles the persistent storage of your app. Here an array is holding the data to be shown in the tableview.  In `commitEditingStyle:`, the Core Data deletion operation done removes the object at that indexpath from the database but the array retrieved by `NSArray *places=[self containerWithSection:section];` needs to be updated as well to reflect the database operation on UI. Hence, there is a need of array updater function, which in our case is the `updateItemInSection:`.
Hope this explains it clearly.

Comment: Ok, yes, quite clear - i'll try to write the method, thanks for the tips

Comment: @FuManchu You should be able to directly use the _above_ `updateItemInSection:` Do accept the answer :)

Comment: @ystak, with these changes, the method number of rows in section doesnt work: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    
    NSArray*places=[self updateItemInSection:section];

    return places.count;

}
Because the method update is void, when it was used to return an array...

Comment: @FuManchu I think you misunderstood me. You _only_ need to change the your current implementation of `commitEditingStyle:` & add the new `updateItemInSection:`. _No other part_ of your code changes, that is why I've only mentioned those 2 functions in the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, ystak, but after a dozen of tests, the code you suggested can only delete the row "clubs" (I have only one object per row). If I try to delete objects from other sections, the app crashes with the same log (invalid update). Inserting and updating in the same session is also a no. Plus, after the crash, if I restart the app, it crashes again, now with the log "index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]"....I dont understand why i can delete the club row and not the others...the logic is the same right? Thank you for your patience :)

Comment: Well, you sure can figure it out, just remember, _on any change, inserting, deletion of data => first, update your data arrays => then,_ `[table reloadData]`

Comment: I've done like you suggested, in this order: delete->updateItemSection and then  [tableView reloadData]; in the edditing method. I can delete the club item with no issues, but not the others. I'm sorry but this is not making sense to me, the table is reloaded as a whole, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136098/discussion-between-fumanchu-and-ystack).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was names confusing...With the edited code, the solution is this:

```
- (void)updateItemInSection:(NSUInteger)section{

    switch (section) {
        case 0:{
            _locations = [[Spot spotWithType:@"users"]mutableCopy];
        }
            break;

        case 1:{
            _users = [[Spot spotType:@"users"]mutableCopy];
        }
            break;    
    }
}
```

But I wouldn't achieve it without the help of @ystack